# Understanding Javascript redirect types condition

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, redirect

I have this code in my website landing page. Overall i noticed it if else condition with different Javascript function. Can anyone explain it? and why `window.location.href === "string"`

`window.location.href` is also a function right?

```
function redirectType() {
  if (typeof window.location.replace === "function") {
    window.location.replace(this.href);
    console.log("window.location.replace");
  } else if (typeof window.location.href === "string") {
    window.location.href = this.href;
    console.log("window.location.href");
  } else if (typeof location.assign === "function") {
    location.assign(this.href);
    console.log("location.assign");
  } else {
    window.open(this.href, "_self");
    console.log("window.open");
  }
}
```

Comment: `window.location.href` is not a function.

Comment: @Pointy is it string? above statement is correct?

Comment: You could open your developer console and type `typeof window.location.href` and find out for sure